# Footer is not coming at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I have developed a page where footer is not coming at bottom of the page , instead of coming at the bottom , footer is coming just after the header.
I have tried almost all the option but I am not able to solve this .

Comment: everything is placed with `position: absolute` without proper markup and offsets.

Comment: I tested it on jsfiddle and it  comes in the footer 
https://jsfiddle.net/w3rz1vwe/

Comment: remove 

#quiz {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    position: absolute;  
}

.survey-form
{   
 width:100%;
}


position:absolute from both

Answer (score 2):

All those absolute positions don't really help. Try position relative instead - see my snippet.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.floatleft {float:left !important;}
.floatright {float:right !important;}
.floatnone {float:none !important;}
.alignleft {text-align:left !important;}
.alignright {text-align:right !important;}
.aligncenter {text-align:center !important;}
.no-display { display:none; }
.no-margin { margin:0 !important; }
.no-padding { padding:0 !important; }
a:focus, button:focus {outline:0px solid}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
.fix {overflow:hidden}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
 color:#000;
}
a {transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover, a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none
}
.clear{clear:both}

#wrapper
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
body {
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#header {
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
}
#logo{
 clear:both;
 margin:20px;
}
#logo a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -18px;
    position: relative;
}

#quiz input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#quiz ol {
   margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
}

#quiz ol li {
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#quiz ol li div {
   padding: 4px 0;
}

#quiz h3 {
   font-size: 17px; margin: 0 0 1px 0; color: #000;
       font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:600;
}

#quiz label
{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight:normal;
}

#results {
    font: 44px Georgia, Serif;
}

center 
{
 font-size:xx-large;
 padding:20px 0 50px 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.form-footer .button {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     background-color: #ecae3d;
  border: 0;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
 font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.form-footer .button:hover{
 
 background-color:#DBDBDB;
 color:#000;
}

#quiz {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    position: relative;
    
}

#footer{
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#2D2D2D;
 color:#9C9C9C;
 clear:both;
}

#footer #footer-center
{
 font-size:18px;
 margin:auto;
 font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 clear:both;
 padding:20px 0 0 0 ;
 
}

.survey-form
{   
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/responsive.css"/>
</head>
<body class="no-transition stretched">

<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<header id="header" class="full-header">

     <!-- Logo-->
     <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo"><img src="images/sequreone-logo.png" alt="Secqureone Logo"></a>
     </div><!-- #logo end -->
</header> 
  
  <div class="survey-form" id="form">
  
  <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="quiz">
  
            <ol>
            
                <li>
                
                    <h3>Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) Yes </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) No</label>
                    </div>
    
                
                </li>
                
                <li>
                
                    <h3>Does Your Business follow one or more of these Standards/Compliance regulations ?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A. PCI" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-A">A) PCI</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B. HIPAA" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-B">B) HIPAA</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-C" value="C. FISMA" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-C">C) FISMA</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-D" value="D. GLBA" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-D">D) GLBA</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-E" value="E. SOX" required />
                        <label for="question-2-answers-E">E) SOX</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-F" value="F. ISO27001" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-F">F) ISO 27001</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-G" value="G. others" required/>
                        <label for="question-2-answers-G">G) Others</label> <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                  
                
                </li>
                
                <li>
                
                    <h3>Does Your Business have a Backup and Recovery Plan?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-3-answers-A">A) Yes </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-3-answers-B">B) No </label>
                    </div>
      
                
                </li>
                
                <li>
                
                    <h3>Does Your Business have end-point anti-virus protection in all desktops and laptops?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-4-answers-A">A) Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-4-answers-B">B) No</label>
                    </div>
                   
                </li>
                
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>Does Your Business perform regular patch management to keep servers, desktops, laptops up-to-date?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-5-answers-A">A) Yes </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-5-answers-B">B) No </label>
                    </div>
      
                
                </li>
    
                <li>
                
                    <h3>Is Your Business email system protected against spam,phising and other email threats ?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-6-answers-A">A) Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-6-answers" id="question-6-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-6-answers-B">B) No</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your Business perform Vulnerability Assessment on your IT Insfrastructure & Networks?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-A" value="A. Every Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-7-answers-A">A) Every Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-B" value="B. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-7-answers-B">B) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-C" value="C. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-7-answers-C">C) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-D" value="D. Yearly" required/>
                        <label for="question-7-answers-D">D) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-7-answers" id="question-7-answers-E" value="E. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-7-answers-E">E) Never Done </label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
    
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your Business perform Penetration Testing on your IT Insfrastructure & Networks?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-A" value="A. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-8-answers-A">A) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-B" value="B. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-8-answers-B">B) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-C" value="C. Yearly " required/>
                        <label for="question-8-answers-C">C) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-8-answers" id="question-8-answers-D" value="D. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-8-answers-D">D) Never Done</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your Business perform security scanning of your website?</h3>
                    
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-A" value="A. Every Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-9-answers-A">A) Every Month</label>
                    </div>
     
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-B" value="B. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-9answers-A">B) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-C" value="C. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-9-answers-C">C) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-D" value="D. Yearly" required/>
                        <label for="question-9-answers-D">D) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-9-answers" id="question-9-answers-E" value="E. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-9-answers-E">E) Never Done</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your company perform a firewall audit?</h3>
                    
                       <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-A" value="A. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-10-answers-A">A) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-B" value="B. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-10-answers-B">B) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-C" value="C. Yearly" required/>
                        <label for="question-10-answers-C">C) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-D" value="D. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-10-answers-D">D) Never Done</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
      <li>
                
                    <h3>Does your business have offsite storage of critical data backups?</h3>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-11-answers" id="question-11-answers-A" value="A. Yes" required/>
                        <label for="question-11-answers-A">A) Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-11-answers" id="question-11-answers-B" value="B. No" required/>
                        <label for="question-11-answers-B">B) No</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your company perform a Risk Assessment?</h3>
                    
                       <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-12-answers" id="question-12-answers-A" value="A. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-12-answers-A">A) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-12-answers" id="question-12-answers-B" value="B. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-11-answers-B">B) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-12-answers" id="question-12-answers-C" value="C. Yearly" required/>
                        <label for="question-12-answers-C">C) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-12-answers" id="question-12-answers-D" value="D. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-12-answers-D">D) Never Done</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
    <li>
                
                    <h3>How Frequently does your company perform security audit of the cloud based application that you use?</h3>
                    
                       <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-13-answers" id="question-13-answers-A" value="A. Every 3 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-13-answers-A">A) Every 3 Month</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-13-answers" id="question-13-answers-B" value="B. Every 6 Month" required/>
                        <label for="question-13-answers-B">B) Every 6 Month</label>
                    </div>
     
     <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-13-answers" id="question-13-answers-C" value="C. Yearly" required/>
                        <label for="question-13-answers-C">C) Yearly </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-13-answers" id="question-13-answers-D" value="D. Never Done" required/>
                        <label for="question-13-answers-D">D) Never Done</label>
                    </div>

                </li>
    
            
            </ol>
            
            <div class="form-footer text-left">
                        <button type="submit" data-btntext-sending="Next" class="button btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        
                    </div>  

  
  </form>
  
  <div id="footer">
  
  <center id="footer-center"> Copyright &copy; 2016 XYZcorp,Inc. All rights reserved </center>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
 
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```